# How to use reloadRowsAtIndexPaths?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have seen this code around lots but not sure how to actually implement it.

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPathOfYourCell] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Is it possible to use this to change the font size of an individual cell in a table that is populated dynamically?

I have the row number of the cell that I want to change and want to change the font size on a timer after x seconds of only the one cell in a table. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowNumber section:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

This is assuming you have code in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method to conditionally change the font size.

Comment: There is no need for the calls to beginUpfates and endUpdates in this case.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without cellForRowAtIndexPath and put the font size code in say a -(void) method?